# how to get value of listbox item by item template

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, telerik, itemtemplate

I have a listbox. And I am using item template. like that

```
<telerik:RadListBox ID="lbOutputColumns" CssClass="RadListBox2" runat="server"
    SelectionMode="Multiple" AllowReorder="true" AutoPostBackOnReorder="true" EnableDragAndDrop="true"
    Skin="" Width="300px">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="variables-list" style="width: 300px !important">
            <span><%# Container.DataItem %></span>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="USA"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
        <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="Turkey"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
        <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="Greece"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
    </Items>
</telerik:RadListBox>
```

When I used

```
<%# Container.DataItem %>
```

listbox doesnt show me items text. how can I get text in radlistboxitem by using item template.

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside the `<ItemTemplate>` block:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "Text") %>
```